# Distribute a decryption key through Remote Notification Service on the phone?

Tags: ios, security, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to use remote notification service(Apple APN or Android GCM) to send info to an app in the foreground(currently running).

```
//This is register the iOS  app with Remote Notification Server   
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                                                   UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
//Successfully registered since user allowed it    
-(void)application:.. didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
                                                            (NSData *)deviceToken;
```

For security purpose, I'm sending some encrypted message from server to my app directly, and I'm trying to send the decryption key through Remote Notification Service, to make sure this decryption key won't be received by any other app, hence improve the security somehow.

```
//this is how I receive notification in iOS app    
-(void)application:.. didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

Since I don't need to alert the user when the app is not running in the foreground, I only want to send info to a running app through a third Authority, Is this a reasonable approach to distribute a cryptography key?

What if the user disabled the notification on the phone?

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple RSA encryption should do just what you need.

I would just preload the app with a public key. And then any messages I am sending over the wire I would have my services encrypt with my private key. If you are trying to get a key to apps that are already on the users devices, I would still preload the key and just update my app.